# Redis ACL Security is not supported by Redisson library

Tags: java, redis, acl, redisson

In our project, we are using a shared Redis server as our cache server. Our DB admin uses Redis ACL Security with a certain key prefix for each Redis username. I've encountered a problem when I want to use Redisson library with Jcache as follows: Redisson uses some other keys like "jcache_sync" , "jcache_timeout:{name}" and so on in order to keep track of cache state and manage expired key. But the problem is that my Redis username does not have the required permission to insert those in Redis and I get a permission error. Is there any solution to tell Redisson to use a prefix for all its internal keys? or configure redis acl security on Redisson config?

[https://redis.io/topics/acl#:~:text=The%20Redis%20ACL%2C%20short%20for,keys%20that%20can%20be%20accessed](https://redis.io/topics/acl#:%7E:text=The%20Redis%20ACL%2C%20short%20for,keys%20that%20can%20be%20accessed).

Comment: you can add acl for all jcache_* keys

Comment: This should solve the problem. but if different applications create two different caches with the same name it could lead to a conflict. We've decided to use different databases for different applications but in the Redis cluster, we do not have separate databases and all applications must use database 0. It would be nice if we could define a prefix for all static keys in Redisson. Thank you.